# OpenCL - How to I query for a device's SIMD width?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

In CUDA, there is a concept of a *warp*, which is defined as the maximum number of threads that can execute the same instruction simultaneously within a single processing element.  For NVIDIA, this warp size is 32 for all of their cards currently on the market.

In ATI cards, there is a similar concept, but the terminology in this context is *wavefront*.  After some hunting around, I found out that the ATI card I have has a wavefront size of 64.

My question is, what can I do to query for this SIMD width at runtime for OpenCL?

Comment: There is no such thing as a wave in CUDA, that is ATI specific terminology. The "SIMD width" is known as a warp. Wavefront is also an AMD architecture specific term, and nothing defined in the OpenCL specification.

Comment: Whoops!  I fixed the typo.  Ok, this is helpful to know for terminology sake, but how am I supposed to know what the "SIMD width" is for the machine the program is running on?  Is there a way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for.  It turns out that you don't query the device for this information, you query the kernel object (in OpenCL).  My source is:

http://www.hpc.lsu.edu/training/tutorials/sc10/tutorials/SC10Tutorials/docs/M13/M13.pdf

(Page 108)

which says:

> The most efficient work group sizes are likely to be multiples of the native hardware execution width
>
> - wavefront size in AMD speak/warp size in Nvidia speak
> - Query device for CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE

So, in short, the answer appears to be to call the clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo() method with a param name of CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE.  See this link for more information on this method:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html

Comment: Keep in mind that `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE` is not guaranteed to be the SIMD size (number of channels in the execution mask). That said, depending on what you're doing, the above query is a good choice for what it reports.

Comment: it seems that the closet to actual SIMD width is the result of `get_max_sub_group_size()`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093488/opencl-how-to-i-query-for-a-devices-simd-width#69494100)

Answer (score 7):

On AMD, you can query CL_DEVICE_WAVEFRONT_WIDTH_AMD.  That's different from CL_DEVICE_SIMD_WIDTH_AMD, which returns the number of threads it executes in each clock cycle.  The latter may be smaller than the wavefront size, in which case it takes multiple clock cycles to execute one instruction for all the threads in a wavefront.

Answer (score 5):

On NVIDIA, you can query the warp size width using clGetDeviceInfo with CL_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE_NV (although this is always 32 for current GPUs), however, this is an extension, as OpenCL defines nothing like warps or wavefronts. I don't know about any AMD extension that would allow to query for the wavefront size.

Answer (score 3):

For AMD: clGetDeviceInfo(..., **CL_DEVICE_WAVEFRONT_WIDTH_AMD**, ...) (if **cl_amd_device_attribute_query** extension supported)

For Nvidia: clGetDeviceInfo(..., **CL_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE_NV**, ...) (if **cl_nv_device_attribute_query** extension supported)

But there is **no uniform way**. The way suggested by Jonathan DeCarlo doesn't work, I was using it for GPUs if these two extensions does not supported - for example Intel iGPU, but recently I faced wrong results on **Intel HD 4600**:

**Intel HD 4600** says **CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE=32** while in fact Intel GPUs seems to have wavefront equal to 16, so I faced incorrect results, everything works fine if barriers were used for wavefront=16.

P.S. I have not enough reputation to comment Jonathan DeCarlo answer about this, will be glad if somebody will add comment.

Comment: For Intel graphics the SIMD size can actually be 8, 16, or 32, depending on the kernel compiled and how many registers it uses.  You can get query the chosen SIMD size via `get_sub_group_size` internally or `CL_KERNEL_MAX_SUB_GROUP_SIZE_FOR_NDRANGE` externally if the `cl_intel_subgroup` extension is supported (Skylake or higher).

Comment: @Tim I'm new to openCL, but it seems to me that in strict terms `get_max_sub_group_size` is better to get SIMD width, no? `get_sub_group_size` called in the last subgroup may return something smaller: for example if group size is 40, and SIMD width is 32 then `get_sub_group_size` will return 32 for threads 0..31 and 8 for threads 32..39, right?

Comment: @Tim I've just tested it: for threads 32..39 `get_sub_group_size` returned 8.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming uniform workgroup size.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to actual SIMD width is the result of `get_max_sub_group_size()` kernel runtime function from [cl_khr_subgroups extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/cl_khr_subgroups.html). It returns `min(SIMD-width, work-group-size)`.

Worth attention is also function `get_sub_group_size()` which returns the size of the current sub-group, which is never bigger than SIMD width: for example if SIMD width is 32 and group size is 40, then `get_sub_group_size` for threads 0..31 will return 32 and for threads 32..39, it will return 8.

foot-note: to use this extension add `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_subgroups : enable` at the top of your openCL kernel code.

**UPDATE:**
it seems that there's also corresponding host level function [clGetKernelSubGroupInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/clGetKernelSubGroupInfo.html), but jocl that I use does not have a binding for it, so I cannot verify if it works.
Currently, if I need to check SIMD width at the host level, I run a helper kernel which calls `get_max_sub_group_size()` and stores it into its result buffer:

```c
// run it with max work-group size
__kernel void getSimdWidth(__global uint *simdWidth) {
    if (get_local_id(0) == 0) simdWidth[0] = get_max_sub_group_size();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the clGetDeviceInfo to get maximum number of workitems you can have in your local workset for each dimension. This is most likely multiple of your wavefront size.

See: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html

Answer (score -2):

For CUDA (using NVIDIA), please take a look at B.4.5 Cuda programming guide from NVIDIA. There is a variable for containing this information. You can query this variable at runtime. For AMD , I'm not sure if there is such a variable.