# OpenCL: Thread-block algebra for intel HD graphics

Tags: opencl, intel

I have some background on  NVIDIA, and so to learn OpenCL for Intel, I would like to correlate.

In case of Nvidia, we have following rules :

1- Warp size: 32 (or in some cases 64)

2- Maximum no. of resident blocks per multiprocessor: 8

3- Maximum no. of  threads that can be resident on a Multiprocessor: 768 ( in older cards)

4- Amount of shared memory available per workgroup: 64 KB (48 + 16 KB )

5- No. of threads per workgroup: 512 (on latest cards it is 1024)

6- A workgroup runs only on a single Multiprocessor i.e half on MP#1 and other half on MP#2 , is not possible.

I would like to know these values for Intel HD graphics.

I will really appreciate if somebody can point me to some links where I may be able to educate myself on this.

Where would I get such info for intel HD graphics? Specifically I have Intel NUC with Celeron N2820 SoC

Answer (score 0):

I like to use CLInfo to dump the details about the hardware. Try to find a pre-compiled binary, or look up the source code.

This link looks promising: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~yoel/notes/clInfo.c

Answer (score 0):

Intel has posted slides on [OpenCL capabilities of Intel Iris Graphics](https://intel.activeevents.com/sz14/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=1260) that were presented at the Intel Developer Forum in April 2014. There is also the [The Compute Architecture of Intel® Processor Graphics Gen7.5](https://software.intel.com/en-us/file/compute-architecture-of-intel-processor-graphics-gen7dot5-aug4-2014pdf) which has a lot of information. Between the two of these, there are answers to most of your questions. However there are sometimes not direct analogs to the NVIDIA concepts because of the different way Intel maps OpenCL to their architecture.

Intel characterizes their different graphics SKUs based on the number of Execution Units (EUs) used in each. The Intel Iris Graphics referenced in the slides has 40 EUs. For your case, the [Developer’s Guide for Intel® Processor Graphics For 4th Generation Intel® Core™ Processors](https://software.intel.com/en-us/file/4th-gen-core-graphics-dev-guidepdf), shows that Intel HD Graphics has 20 EUs. You ask about multiprocessors -- the Intel equivalent is a "subslice", which is a group of 10 EUs. So Intel HD Graphics you are using has 2 subslices.

From all this we can derive some of the answers you're looking for...

1- Warp size: Unclear how Intel HD graphics models this concept. This [SO thread on querying preferred SIMD width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093488/opencl-how-to-i-query-for-a-devices-simd-width) may be helpful.

2- Maximum no. of resident blocks per multiprocessor/subslice: Intel only states that this is limited by the use of the 16 barrier registers per subslice. Potentially 70.

3- Maximum no. of threads that can be resident on a Multiprocessor/subslice: 70.

4- Amount of shared memory available per workgroup: No answer per workgroup, but per subslice there is 64KB shared local memory + 128KB L3 cache.

5- No. of threads per workgroup: Not stated. The answer to the next question implies that this number could be as high as the maximum number of threads runnable on the 2 subslices: 140.

6- A workgroup runs only on a single Multiprocessor/subslice: Under certain conditions, more is possible on Intel HD Graphics. From the [Compute Architecture reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/file/compute-architecture-of-intel-processor-graphics-gen7dot5-aug4-2014pdf):

> For compute workloads that do not depend upon hardware barriers nor
>   upon shared local memory, thread dispatch global may choose to
>   distribute the workload over all available slices... For compute
>   workloads that do depend upon hardware barriers or shared local
>   memory, thread dispatch global will assign work-group (aka
>   thread-group) sized portions of the workload to specific subslices.