# Is OpenCL SubSlice analogous to CUDA Warp (SIMD)?

Tags: opencl, simd

Short background:

In CUDA, we have the concept of warps, which is 32 threads which are guaranteed to be synchronized. I have a kernel which depends on this SIMD behavior to avoid the potential overhead of a whole bunch of synchronization calls (after some loops, 1 thread finishes and writes a value in shared memory, which the remaining threads use for their calculations).

So are there any way to image this behavior in OpenCL with e.g. Sub_Slices? [According to Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/540425) it seems like they work like this, but is there any feature in OpenCL which guarentees SIMD behaviour?

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that "slice" (or "subslice") is an explicit part of OpenCL standard terminology.  I may be wrong, but I think it is not.  I think it may be specific to Intel designs, at least insofar as the context you are using it in here.  Certainly the word "slice" does appear in [the OpenCL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-2.0.pdf) but it is used only as a naming convention to refer to a specific layer in a multidimensional data structure.  As far as I can tell, "subslice" does not appear at all in the OpenCL standard spec.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you for pointing that out. I have tried to clarify that i didn't intend to make the question explicitly about subslices, but SIMD in general.

Answer (score 3):

For `OpenCL` on `NVIDIA` these are called `warps` too and typically have 32 work items. On `AMD` that is a `wavefront` with 64 work items. On `Intel` this can be `SIMD-8` or `SIMD-16` or `SIMD-32` (8/16/32 work items) that can fit on a hardware thread and be executed simultaneously. Whether that is `SIMD-8` or `SIMD-16` or `SIMD-32` it's depending on the compiler choice.

The information can usually be retrieved from the `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE` parameter in the `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093488/opencl-how-to-i-query-for-a-devices-simd-width?rq=1 said the same. But what is missing is whether CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE is guarenteed to be the SIMD Width and work this way. Otherwise my algorithm will produce the wrong result.

Comment: See [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/540486). It doesn't explicitly confirm it though. You may want to dig more in that guide.

Comment: Intel does not call these subslices. They call them "(SIMD) threads". A subslice is a collection of EUs (execution units) each which can choose among 7 SIMD threads.

Comment: `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE` will not necessarily be the SIMD width. While it typically is, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Tim indeed that is not called a subslice - fixed. Re. `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE` I think _can usually be retrieved_ already express that.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is a useful idiom.  I think what you're  looking for is the OpenCL [subgroups](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/intel/cl_intel_subgroups.txt) extension. A "subgroup" is equivalent to a HW thread (Intel's word for "wave").

A subslice is actually a collection of EUs, each of which have 7 "SIMD threads" (waves).  However, they all share a sampler, data port, instruction cache, and texture cache.