# Are there any 'warp size' or 'wavefront width' equivalent on Intel GPUs

Tags: opencl

On Nvidia there is `CL_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE_NV` query put into `clGetDeviceInfo` that usually returns 32.

On AMD there is `CL_DEVICE_WAVEFRONT_WIDTH_AMD` that was 64 in the past and now on more recent AMD GPUs it is also 32.

Intel have a set of queries, I suppose some multiplies of them are equivalent of 'warp size' or not. They are: `CL_DEVICE_NUM_SLICES_INTEL`, `CL_DEVICE_NUM_SUB_SLICES_PER_SLICE_INTEL`,
`CL_DEVICE_NUM_EUS_PER_SUB_SLICE_INTEL`, `CL_DEVICE_NUM_THREADS_PER_EU_INTEL`.

For Intel HD530 in order of appearance values are 1, 3, 8, 7. For Intel Arc A380: 2, 8, 8, 8. For Intel Arc A750: 7, 8, 8, 8.

Usually this 'warp size' queries used to determine amount of shared memory buffer, to determine 'maximal amount of threads device capable of' etc.

I have read 'Introduction to the Xe-HPG Architecture' but still in doubt what is 'warp size' on Intel.

Answer (score 2):

Intel publishes an [OpenCL developer Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/774834/opencl-developer-guide-for-intel-processor-graphics.html) which I would strongly recommend reading in detail. The first chapter, *"Execution of OpenCL™ Work-Items: the SIMD Machine"* explains what slices, sub-slices and EUs are.

Unlike AMD and Nvidia GPUs, the Intel GPUs seem to have more flexible SIMD groupings:

> The SIMD-width for kernel is a heuristic driven compiler choice. SIMD-8, SIMD-16, SIMD-32 are common SIMD- width examples.

The first chapter ends with a section, *"Work-Group Size Recommendations Summary"*, which has the following to say:

> If your kernel uses local memory and/or barriers, […] per sub-slice […] no more than 16 work-groups can be executed simultaneously. […] The amount of shared local memory available per sub-slice (64KB). […] A bare minimum SLM allocation size is 4k per workgroup

and:

> Therefore, to keep the device utilization high with the limited number of workgroups, larger workgroup sizes are required. Use power-of-two workgroup sizes between 64 and 256.

But if not using local memory, the recommendation is different:

> If your kernel is not using local memory or barriers, these restrictions do not apply, and work-group size of 32 work-items is optimal for the[sic] most cases.

Comment: Thank you. I am extensively using Intel's `cl_intel_driver_diagnostics` extension to tune up  performance, and its recommended local sizes seems to be always multiply of 32. Second indicator was this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71578518/1093791 from Vulkan's side, and it seems that `VkPhysicalDeviceSubgroupProperties.subgroupSize` are the same value as `CL_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE_NV` on Nvidia and `CL_DEVICE_WAVEFRONT_WIDTH_AMD` on AMD. On currently accessible Intel Arc A750 it reports 32.

Comment: FYI, the Intel Iris Graphics 6100 in my 2015 MacBook Pro reports a SIMD group size of 8 in Metal Compute shaders on macOS. Unfortunately, the `cl_intel_driver_diagnostics` extension isn't supported in OpenCL on MacOS, and I'm not sure what standards-compliant OpenCL 1.2 query I could run to get the equivalent information.

Comment: `cl_intel_driver_diagnostics` is about performance hints, not the device properties query. You can try to put mentioned Intel-only `CL_DEVICE_NUM_SLICES_INTEL`, `CL_DEVICE_NUM_SUB_SLICES_PER_SLICE_INTEL`, `CL_DEVICE_NUM_EUS_PER_SUB_SLICE_INTEL`, `CL_DEVICE_NUM_THREADS_PER_EU_INTEL` into `clGetDeviceInfo` on your Intel device as well with standard `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` to get some info how to multiply all those numbers.